# Why int& a = <value> is not allowed in C++?

Tags: c++, pass-by-reference

I am reading about references in C++. It says that `int& a = 5` gives compile time error.

In *Thinking in C++ - Bruce Eckel*, author says that compiler must first allocate the storage for an **int** and produce the address to bind to the reference. The storage *must* be **const** because *changing it would make no sense*.

I am confused at this point. I am not able to understand the logic behind it. Why can't be change the content in the storage? I understand that it's invalid as per C++ rules, but why?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How come a non-const reference cannot bind to a temporary object?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1565600/how-come-a-non-const-reference-cannot-bind-to-a-temporary-object)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> *"The storage must be const because changing it would make no sense."*

If you want `a` be a reference to a const value, you must declare it as `const`, because `a` is referencing to a temporary constant value, and changing it is not possible.

```
const int &a = 123;
a = 1000; // `a` is referencing to temporary 123, it is not possible to change it
          // We can not change 123 to 1000
          // Infact, we can change a variable which its value is 123 to 1000
          // Here `a` is not a normal variable, it's a reference to a const
          // Generally, `int &a` can not bind to a temporary object
```

For non-const bindings:

```
int x = 1;
int &a = x;
```

`a` is a reference to a lvalue. Simple speaking, it's an alias name for another variable, so on the right hand you should give a variable. The reference `a` can not change and bind to another variable after it's first binding;

In C++11, you can reference to temporary objects/values by rvalue references:

```
int &&a = 123;
```

Answer (score 5):

```
int& a = 5;
```

In order for the above code to work, `int&` needs to bind to a temporary object of type `int` created out of the expression `5`. But binding `int&` to a temporay didn't appeal to Bjarne Stroustrup — and he gave an example, similar to the following, to illustrate his point:

```
void f(int &i) { ++i; }

float x = 10.0;
f(x); 
std::cout << x <<< std::endl;
```

What will the `std::cout` print<sup>1</sup>? Looks like it will print `11`.

It *feels*, `++i` is changing the argument `x`, but it doesn't. This is one reason why the creator of C++ didn't permit temporaries to bind to non-const reference.

However, you can do this:

```
int const & i = 10;
int const & j = x; //x is float
```

And since C++11, you can do this:

```
int && i = 10;
int && i = x; //x is float
```

Hope that helps.

---

<sup>1. assuming `int&` can bind to the temporary created out of `x`.</sup>

Comment: +1 for the `f()` example: **THIS**. I've occasionally wondered about why l-refs can't bind to temporaries myself, but never thought of that one. Thanks for broadening my horizons :-)

Comment: Thanks for replying. So what I conclude from your answer is that _Bjarne Stroustrup just made it like that_. I just want to make sure I am not missing some logic that is there behind this whole concept!

Answer (score 0):

What you can do is

```
int b=5;
int &a=b;
```

or

```
const int& a = 5;
```