# Inconsistent behaviour passing arguments in C++

Tags: c++, compiler-errors, arguments

Given these two function declarations:

```
void initialize(int p, std::vector<Vector3> &);
std::vector<Vector3> toNurbsCoords(std::vector<Vector3>);
```

why does this work

```
Nurbs nurbs;
std::vector<Vector3> pts = nurbs.toNurbsCoords(points);
nurbs.initialize(degree, pts);
```

while this throws a compile time error?

```
Nurbs nurbs;    
nurbs.initialize(degree, nurbs.toNurbsCoords(points));
//error: no matching function for call to 'Nurbs::initialize(int&, std::vector<Vector3>)'
```

Comment: For more info, see [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/19375634/1782465).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because a temporary can't bind to a non-`const` reference.

`nurbs.toNurbsCoords(points)` is a temporary. In the first case you initialize named object - `pts` - with it and pass that. In the second case, you just pass the temp.

Comment: Small correction: "a temporary can't bind to a non-const **lvalue** reference." (Recall that a temporary can bind to a non-const **rvalue** reference.)